# Index Outside of Bounds on Stock Maximization Algorithm

Tags: java, c#

I have the following [code](https://github.com/mission-peace/interview/blob/master/src/com/interview/dynamic/StockBuySellKTransactions.java) translated as best I could from Java to C#:

```
public double maxProfit(double[] prices, int K)
        {
            if (K == 0 || prices.Length == 0)
            {
                return 0;
            }

            var dp = new double[K + 1, prices.Length];

            for (int i = 1; i < K + 1; i++)
            {
                double maxDiff = -prices[0];
                for (int j = 1; j < prices.Length; j++)
                {
                    dp[i, j] = Math.Max(dp[i, j - 1], prices[j] + maxDiff);
                    maxDiff = Math.Max(maxDiff, dp[i - 1, j] - prices[j]);
                }
            }

            printTrans(dp, prices, K);


            return dp[K, prices.Length - 1];
        }

        public void printTrans(double[,] dp, double[] prices, int K)
        {
            int i = K - 1;
            int j = prices.Length;

            var priceList = new List<double>();
            while (true)
            {
                if (i == 0 || j == 0)
                {
                    break;
                }

                if (dp[i, j] == dp[i, j - 1])
                {
                    j = j - 1;
                }
                else
                {
                    priceList.Add(j);
                    double maxDiff = dp[i, j] - prices[j];
                    for (int z = j - 1; z >= 0; z--)
                    {
                        if (dp[i - 1, z] - prices[z] == maxDiff)
                        {
                            i = i - 1;
                            j = z;
                            priceList.Add(j);
                            break;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }

            while (priceList.Count > 0)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Buy @ " + prices[priceList.IndexOf(0)]);
                Console.WriteLine("Sell @ " + prices[priceList.IndexOf(0)]);
            }
        }
```

Error occurs in the second method on lines:

```
if (dp[i, j] == dp[i, j - 1])
```

and

```
 for (int z = j - 1; z >= 0; z--)
  {
   if (dp[i - 1, z] - prices[z] == maxDiff)
```

I am getting an `Index was outside the bounds of the array`. error. I understand what this error means but I have no clue on my to fix it. It took me quite a bit to understand the first part of this code but for the second part, I am at a loss.

Also what is the C# equivalent of the Java `pollFirst()` method?

Comment: what line are you getting the error?

Comment: @MiguelSanchez I have edited the answer to show where the error occurs.

Comment: The equivalent of [pollFirst()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/LinkedList.html) assuming you're using .NET [LinkedList](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/he2s3bh7.aspx) is [First](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms132187.aspx) and if it's not null, call [RemoveFirst](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms132181.aspx)

Comment: The error is occurring because your `j` variable is exceeding the bounds of the 2D array, please correct your code to ensure it is within limits

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably this line is the cause

```
 public void printTrans(double[,] dp, double[] prices, int K)
        {
            int i = K - 1;
            int j = prices.Length; // <=== this line is the cause
```

its causing the `j` to refer an index outside the bounds  of the 2D array.

If you have ported from `java` recheck your java code.

Either make that line

```
int j = prices.Length - 1;
```

Or you need to make changes to how you create your array

```
 var dp = new double[K + 1, prices.Length]; // <-- prices.Length would have to change here
```

Comment: well i feel dumb. Thanks for the help!